# Region monitoring in iOS: didEnterRegion fires but didExitRegion does not in simuator

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I am using CLLocationManager to monitor regions in iOS. I set up the delegate in the normal way:

```
self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
```

and implement several delegate functions including:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
   NSLog(@"GeoFence: didEnterRegion");    
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region 
{
    NSLog(@"GeoFence: didExitRegion");    
}
```

Then I start monitoring a region with:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng);     
CLRegion *grRegion = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:coordinates radius:radius identifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"grRegion%i", 1]];

CLLocationAccuracy acc = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:grRegion desiredAccuracy:acc];
```

with appropriate values for lat (51.116261), lng (-0.85300) and radius (200). After building and running the app in the iPhone 5.1 simulator, I use the location injection tool in Xcode 4.3 to move between a distant location to my target location and back again. Under this procedure, the didEnterRegion event correctly triggers but the didExitRegion never does. I also receive other delegate callbacks such as didUpdateToLocation. I have varied the pattern of simulated movements, used the simulator's location setting tool rather than Xcode's, and tried the same tests running the app on an iPhone 4S with iOS 5.1. All tests have the same result.

I have ensured WiFi is enabled as suggested in other threads and looked through other questions on related topics in vain. Any suggestions as why one of the region transition events would fire, but not the other?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue in 5.1. I filed a radar with Apple as a bug. It would trip the first event, in or out, but no other events after that.

From what I can see, this issue has been resolved in the iOS 6 beta. So look for it to be resolved when iOS 6 goes live.

Radar: 11715223

Comment: The problem with region monitoring in the simulator stall exists in iOS 6.1.1.

Comment: I agree, the issue is still happening. This answer is a bit dated. FWIW, Apple still hasn't updated the radar, so the issue is still out there. Feel free to dupe the radar.